# passing argument to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

How I can pass argument to reqestAnimationFrame ?
let's say I have this code,how I can pass argument to requestAnimationFrame

```
var element = document.getElementById("SomeElementIWantToAnimate");
element.style.position = 'absolute';

function step(number) {
element.style.left = ""+Math.min(progress/10, 200) + "px";
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step); //how I can pass a "number" argument here
```

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) { step(yourNumberGoesHere);})`

Comment: Or use `.bind()`.

Comment: how I can use bind?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is current timestamp, not a step and you need to call requestAnimationFrame again and again until your animation is done

I find this solution while I develop a small library
I have created one, which is very simple and small

https://github.com/allenhwkim/jsanimation

Usage

```
import {slideInRight} from 'jsanimation';
slideInRight(el);
```